# how to pre-fill write something text in facebook post to friends wall

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Hi i am using following code to post to friends wall which is working fine.
i want to prefill that text in text view where it says write something on friend's wall.
is it possible to edit it ? if yes then how ?
here is the code

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                               @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                               @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",
                               @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                               @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                               @"100006771363037",@"to",
                                nil];

// Show the feed dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                            if (error) {
                                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                              NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                            } else {
                                              if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                // User canceled.
                                                NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                              } else {
                                                // Handle the publish feed callback
                                                NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                                if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                                  // User canceled.
                                                  NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                                                } else {
                                                  // User clicked the Share button

                                                    NSLog(@"fb web dialog result=====>%@",result);
                                                  NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                                  NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                                                }
                                              }
                                            }
                                          }];
```

Comment: 1+ for neat code and good indentations and proper comments. Try to keep the habit forever. (:

Answer (score 0):

thats definitely possible:
set the text of your textview to the desired pre filled text:

```
textView.text = @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.";
```

and use the textViews's text for the dictionary you are sending to Facebook, maybe via some self defined method like

```
- (void)postToFacebookWithCaption:(NSString*)caption text:(NSString*)text{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                           caption, @"caption",
                           text, @"description",
                           @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                           @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                           @"100006771363037",@"to",
                            nil];

    //insert code to show the feed dialog
}
```